# a table to be stored in an excel format

Tags: qlikview

a table to be stored in an excel format with the time stamp variable
but post adding let Time variable the file has been generated but an error found while opening the excel "Cannot open file"

Answer (score -2):

```
LET vTime = Timestamp(Now(),'DD-MM-YYYY hhmmss');
```

Try adding the above then it would solve the issue